# Copying a pointer of a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have the following code snippet:

```
struct client {
        char* ip_address;
        int port;
        struct timeval last_seen;
};

/* setup socket */

struct client** clients = malloc(0);
unsigned int n_clients = 0;

for (uint32_t iter = 0; ; iter++) {

        /* some socket code, that populates client_ip_address, client_prt and timestamp */

        n_clients++;
        struct client client = {client_ip_address, client_port, timestamp};

        clients = realloc(clients, n_clients * sizeof(struct client*));
        memcpy(clients[n_clients-1], client, sizeof client);
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to keep track of the IP, port and timestamp of all of the clients that connect to my socket, inside of the array `clients`. However, the `memcpy` line results in a segmentation fault, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You allocate and reallocate `pointers`, but never allocate storage for the `struct client` themself. You can simplify by declaring `struct client *clients;` instead of pointers then structs. You must further allocate for each `char* ip_address;` as well or make `ip_address` a fixed-size buffer.

Comment: It may not have anything to do with this, but why aren't the any parentheses around 'client' in the memcopy Line, at size of... `memcpy(clients[n_clients-1], client, sizeof client);` shouldn't it be: `memcpy(clients[n_clients-1], client, sizeof( client));`

Comment: @user3801839 `sizeof` is not a normal function. It's a unary operator. The parens are optional.

Comment: I know it is. Just don't ever think I've seen it without the parentheses

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I replaced `clients**` with `clients*` and now I get the error: `realloc(): invalid pointer`, which appears to be to do with the `memcpy` again.

Comment: What does your compiler tell you when you pass `client` into `memcpy` where the address of a memory location is expected? This must be `&client`. You should always enable warnings in your compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, it is not necessary to allocate *pointer to* `struct client` and then allocate for each *struct*. It would make more sense to simply allocate/reallocate an *array of struct*. You also must ensure your:

```
/* some socket code populates ip_address, port and timestamp */
```

actually allocates storage for `char *ip_address;` as it is simply a pointer and must point to valid storage before it is used.

Your allocate/realloc scheme is also slightly out of order. You wan to check whether reallocation is needed before you attempt to use additional storage in your array. Additionally, you always `realloc` to a temporary pointer to avoid loss of the pointer to your data is (and when) `realloc` fails returning `NULL`. If you realloc with the original pointer, e.g. `clients = realloc (clients, ...)` and `realloc` returns `NULL` you overwrite your pointer address with `NULL` losing your pointer and creating a memory-leak.

Shuffling the order around and implementing the use of a temporary pointer, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NSTRUCT 8   /* initial number of struct to allocate */

struct client {
    char *ip_address;   /* must be allocated separately */
    int port;
    struct timeval last_seen;
};

int main (void) {

    size_t  n_clients = 0,          /* number of clients filled */
            n_alloced = NSTRUCT;    /* number of clients allocated */
    struct client *clients = malloc (n_alloced * sizeof *clients);

    if (!clients) { /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-clients");
        return 1;
    }

    for (uint32_t iter = 0; ; iter++) {

        if (n_clients == n_alloced) {   /* check if realloc required */
            /* always realloc with a temporary pointer, or risk data loss */
            void *tmp = realloc (clients, 2 * n_alloced * sizeof *clients);
            if (!tmp) { /* validate reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-clients");
                break;  /* don't exit, original clients still valid */
            }
            clients = tmp;  /* assign reallocated block to clients */
            n_alloced *= 2; /* update allocated number of struct */
        }

        struct client client = {client_ip_address, client_port, timestamp};
        /* some socket code populates ip_address, port and timestamp */
        if (/* client filled correctly */) {
            memcpy (&clients[n_clients], &client, sizeof client);
            n_clients++;
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** storage for `client.ip_address` must be of allocated type, further, since `client` is simply a struct, `clients[n_clients] = client;` is sufficient - and `client` must be fully filled with no other members or sub-members  requiring a *deep-copy* of additional allocated members.)

Don't forget to `free()` the memory you allocate when it is no longer needed.

**Edit - some socket code doesn't allocate for** `client.ip_address`

Since your `struct client` contains a *pointer to char* as the `.ip_address` member, if your `"some socket code"` does not allocate storage for `.ip_address`, you will have to copy that member separately (a deep-copy). Using a simple assignment of members with *automatic-storage duration*, you can allocate and copy `client.ip_address` to `clients[n_clients].ip_address` separately as follows:

```
        /* some socket code populates ip_address, port but doesn't
         * allocate storage for client.ip_address -- you must copy.
         */
        if (/* client filled correctly */) {
            /* assignment is sufficient for non-allocated members */
            clients[n_clients] = client;  
            size_t len = strlen (client.ip_address);
            clients[n_clients].ip_address = malloc (len + 1);
            if (!clients[n_clients].ip_address) {
                perror ("malloc-clients[n_clients].ip_address");
                break;
            }
            memcpy (clients[n_clients].ip_address, client.ip_address,
                    len + 1);
            n_clients++;
        }
```

(that also means you will have to `free()` each `.ip_address` member separately before you free the array)

If your compiler provides `strdup()`, you can simplify the copy of `.ip_address` as:

```
            clients[n_clients].ip_address = strdup (client.ip_address);
            /* strdup allocates -- so you must validate */  
            if (!clients[n_clients].ip_address) {
                perror ("strdup-clients[n_clients].ip_address");
                break;
            }
```

Comment: I implemented these changes, however it still gets a segmentation fault. When I trace with `gdb` it spits out `__memmove_avx_unaligned_erms at ....`, so I think the `memcpy` still fails.

Comment: I've fixed the above error, I forgot to initially allocated memory to `clients`. However, while the now runs, if I add a client with the IP `1.2.3.4` all of the clients in the array become that same client.

Comment: Using `struct client client = {client_ip_address, client_port, timestamp};` is not allocating `client.ip_address`. You must allocate storage and copy. Otherwise all of your stored `clients` will end up pointing to the last filled `ip_address`.

Comment: Good, that was the only sticking point. It should run and allocate/realloc as required up to the limits of physical memory on your computer `:)`

Comment: Yes, however it is no use to me if I have array full only of multiple copies of the same client--how can I make it copy the value, and not the memory address?

Comment: Ah. Got it, thank you, the edit explained it really well!

Answer (score 0):

First we need to deal with the error.

```
cc -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99 -pedantic -g `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 --cflags json-glib-1.0 --cflags json-c`   -c -o test.o test.c
test.c:23:34: error: passing 'struct client' to parameter of incompatible type
      'const void *'
    memcpy(clients[n_clients-1], client, sizeof client);
                                 ^~~~~~
```

`memcpy` takes pointers. `client` does not store a pointer, it stores the whole struct. You need to pass in `&client`.

---

The problem is you're trying to copy a struct where a pointer to a struct should go.

`struct client** clients` is an array of `struct client*`. That its, it's an array of pointers. `clients = realloc(clients, n_clients * sizeof(struct client*));` is allocating space for `n_clients` pointers in `clients`. That's fine.

`memcpy(clients[n_clients-1], &client, sizeof client);` is trying to copy the whole struct into a space that's only supposed to take a pointer. It's shoving 16 bytes into 8 bytes of space (assuming 64 bits).

`client` is using automatic stack memory which will be overwritten as soon as you leave the block. You need to allocate heap memory for it, copy it to that memory, and store the pointer to the heap memory in `clients`.

```
n_clients++;

// Put the struct in stack memory
struct client client = {client_ip_address, client_port};

// Allocate space for the pointer in the list.
clients = realloc(clients, n_clients * sizeof(struct client*));

// Allocate space for the struct in heap memory.
struct client *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct client));

// Copy the struct from stack to heap memory
memcpy(tmp, &client, sizeof client);

// Store the pointer to heap memory
clients[n_clients-1] = tmp;
```

But it's easier to skip the stack memory and allocate `client` as heap memory in the first place.

```
n_clients++;

// Allocate heap memory for the struct.
struct client* client = malloc(sizeof(struct client));

// Initialize the struct.
client->ip_address = client_ip_address;
client->port = client_port;

// Allocate space for the pointer.
clients = realloc(clients, n_clients * sizeof(struct client*));

// Store the pointer.
clients[n_clients-1] = client;
```

Comment: In your second example, the last line causes a compilation error: `incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct client’ from type ‘struct client *’`

Comment: @Mr.King You changed `clients` from `struct client **` (an array of pointers to structs) to `struct client *` (an array of structs). [Here's the full code](https://gist.github.com/schwern/847a664a64fe5dc1c06db7723f66d943).